# VBA Macro in Excel - Using getElementById when the ID is dynamic

Tags: vba, dom, web-scraping, getelementbyid

I am trying to fill out a form on a webpage using data from Excel and a VBA Macro.

```
IE.document.getElementById("elementName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table_1").Range("A2").Value
```

However, the website I am using doesn't have static IDs for the input IDs or the DIV tags.  If I view the source on the webpage I will see this:

```
<div class="username" id="newid181619129-Username" value="">
<input class="search form-control" id="newid181619129-Username_input" type="text" />
</div>
```

And then if I refresh the webpage I get this.

```
<div class="username" id="newid521236985-Username" value="">
<input class="search form-control" id="newid521236985-Username_input" type="text" />
</div>
```

I have no control of the source webpage.  The only solution I found for this was to "Enumerate all descendant `<div>`s of that tag, testing their `ID` property with `Like`." but there isn't a `DIV` tag I can find that uses a static ID.

Is there some way I can get `getElementById` to work with dynamic IDs?

Comment: Sure it is. Try using `.querySelector()` to make use of dynamic IDs. For example, this portion `-Username` and `-Username_input` remain unchanged which you can use to get your job done.

Comment: That looks promising, but I am not sure how exactly the syntax should be.  I got this working on a test site `IE.document.querySelector("#email").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table_1").Range("A2").Value` but when I tried to do a partial match (based on another StackOverflow page I found) it does not work.  `IE.document.querySelector("id$='mail'").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table_1").Range("A2").Value`

Comment: I was missing brackets, `IE.document.querySelector("[id$='mail']").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table_1").Range("A2").Value`

Comment: Did you find it working finally?

Comment: Yes, I did, see my last comment, I was able to make it work.  Thanks!